# How to diagnose frequent internet disconnection issue?

Tags: networking, internet, diagnostic

We are a small team where we have a internet lease line of 50Mbps from our office space provider (they won't allow other internet providers). We have one Ethernet cable coming from them which is plugged in our `TP-Link AC1750` router which further creates a LAN and a wifi network. And we do not have any IT/Networking guy yet in our company.

Most of our internet usage is generally browsing and searching. Now the issue we have is that suddenly our internet stops working from time to time (don't know if it's for all or some - seems like it's atleast from some people).

We have asked our provider to look for the problem on his side, and also tell us how to diagnose any problems on our side, but he is unable to provide any. He says 50Mbps should be enough for us and asked to note timestamp when disconnection's happen :(

**What are the steps/tools(software or hardware) i can use to analyse this issue ?**

One thing i think is we should change our router and use some managed switch (but i don't know which).

Some thing i would to like to know about our network are:

1. How much total bandwidth of the allocated 50Mbps are we using at any given moment and is it falling short (so we can upgrade).
2. Which system is or office is using the most data (some kind of history of it)
3. If we are not choking our bandwidth and still internet is disconnecting, why is that and some kind of historical proof for it so i can show it to our internet provider.

Comment: I suggest you bring in a IT person locally to assist.  This question is too broad to be answered with a single answer and your IT experience is too limited to be able to resolve this quickly in this manner. Stack-Exchange is not designed for a lot of back and forth. 
 A support person will be able to narrow it down quickly and also note things that you omitted that inform the situation.  I mean this all respectfully, not trying to be rude just pragmatic.

Comment: @BlindSpots Thanks for pointing our, but can you suggest me a managed switch which can give such kind of stats, meanwhile we will look for a IT person.